# How do I show a field count in another table?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I am new to SQL and trying to learn by doing some beginner exercises. I'm working in Visual Studio.
I have one table with some Theater shows including Receipt ID, SeatRow and SeatNumbers. 
I have another table consisting of Phone Numbers, Receipt IDs and TheatherShow IDs.

Now I want to make a third table showing how many seats are tied to each Receipt ID.

I've been trying to do this:

```
Update Table_Seat_Count
set Seat_Count = Count(Seat_Number) FROM Plads 
WHERE ReceiptID = ReceiptID
```

Setting the `Seat_Count` equal to the number of seats where the `ReceiptID` is the same within the two tables.

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a sub-select:

```
Update Table_Seat_Count
set Seat_Count = (select Count(Seat_Number) FROM Plads
                  WHERE Plads.ReceiptID = Table_Seat_Count.ReceiptID)
```

But in general it's a good idea to never store computed values. (If Plads is updated, and Table_Seat_Count isn't you've got inconsistent data...) Views are great, with them you'll always have consistent data!

Comment: Thank you very much! :) it worked. I'll accept your answer when I'm allowed to in 11 minutes.